# android edittext limited options to chhose from

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to android development and I have an edittext for which i want to give only limited options to choose from. But I have no idea in this direction.

any example code would be very helpful

Comment: what do you mean by **give only limited options to choose from**?

Comment: for example i want to give a list of limited options clicking on which i can get text for my edittext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need an AutocompleTextView. Take a look at this sample:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

Comment: i wanted to display a list of 5 categories to choose from and on clicking any of them the text of edittext should be set to whatever written in that particular row... but i guess i will make a onclicklistner for that and make edittext be a textview

Comment: Take a look at that sample, it does what you need.